# Stopping ligatures in konsole

Tags: fedora, fonts, kde, konsole, fontconfig

After upgrading to Fedora 29 konsole has started to use ligatures for my monowidth fonts (currently Inconsolata), which is beyond terrible for example when it decides to combine "fi". I have futzed with fontconfig tweaks like the following, to no avail:

```
$ cat ~/.config/fontconfig/fonts.conf
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">
<fontconfig>
  <description>Disable ligatures for monospaced fonts to avoid ff, fi, ffi, etc. becoming only one character wide</description>
  <match target="font">
    <test name="family" compare="contains" ignore-blanks="true">
      <string>Inconsolata</string>
    </test>
    <edit name="fontfeatures" mode="append">
      <string>liga off</string>
      <string>dlig off</string>
    </edit>
  </match>
</fontconfig>
```

I can work around it by switching fonts, but this behavior is just unhelpful. How do I properly prevent konsole from using any kind of ligatures for my fonts?

Comment: Fyi, by now I've figured out that there were two sources at play for the Inconsolata font (fontforge and levien-inconsolata-fonts), and in the latter the font wasn't marked as a monospace one. Still, I am puzzled as to why the fontconfig tweak shown above didn't work.

Comment: "Beyond terrible".  I'll say.  I had the same problem today, and worked around it by switching the Konsole font from Monospace to Courier.  I don't have anything else to offer besides sympathy; sorry.  Perhaps it's been fixed in newer versions.  (I'm using RHEL7 for legacy reasons.)